# Repeated measures with nested data mixed effects model (singularity)

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, pre-post-comparison

I hope you can help me. I performed a pre-post study with two Trainings (ViStra & LeStra), and I measured safety outcomes (e.g. Knowledge, attitudes, behavior, etc...) with questionnaires before (T1) and after (T2) the training (*Time*). Participants (*ID*) took just one of the *Trainings* were nested into 5 *companies*, and we want to know if there are differential changes in the trainings over time.

```
 Participants per company per training          
      V-Training  L-Training
   B  10          14
   C   9          10
   G  18          14
   H   6           8
   K  12          14
   U  31          32
```

Therefore, I used GLMM to evaluate safety training outcomes, like this:

```
Model_A<-lmer(OutcomeMean~ Time*Training + (1|company/ID), data=DataSet)
```

When I run the model, the first warning appears:

```
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

And when I want to calculate the ICC the following message appears:

```
performance::icc(Model_A, by_group=TRUE) 

Can't compute random effect variances. Some variance components equal zero. Your model may suffer from singularity (see `?lme4::isSingular` and `?performance::check_singularity`).
Solution: Respecify random structure! You may also decrease the `tolerance` level to enforce the calculation of random effectn variances.
```

However, when I run the following model (take a look into the random effects):

```
Model_B<-lmer(OutcomeMean ~ Time*Training + (1|ID/company), data=DataSet)
```

No warning appears and it does calculate the ICC. What am I doing wrong? Participants (IDs) are assumed to be nested in companies. Is it possible that it is because within each company there are few participants?

Thank you.

Here you have the Data in Long format (ID is twice as it was tested before and after):

```
OutcomeMean <- as.numeric(c(3.9,4.6,3.6,4.1,4.8,4.7,4.3,5,3.5,3.8,4,4.2,4.6,4.5,3.6,4.2,3.9,4.3,3.6,3.9,4.8,4.3,3.6,4.4,4.5,4.1,4.2,3.6,4.5,4,3.6,4.4,4.3,3.6,3.9,4.2,4.3,4.6,3.5,4.6,4.1,5,3.3,4.5,"NA",5,4.4,3.5,3.6,4.1,3.7,3.9,4.2,4.1,4.1,3.7,3.2,3.4,4.3,3.8,4.6,4,4.3,3.7,4.3,3.6,3.3,3.3,4.1,4,3.4,4.6,4.4,3.1,4.9,4.5,4.1,3.6,4.4,4.5,4.5,3.3,4.4,4.3,4.2,3.1,4.3,3,4.4,"NA",3.7,3.4,4.4,4.3,2.2,5,5,5,4.3,3.6,3.6,3.8,4.2,4.9,5,3.6,4.2,5,4.3,3.8,4,5,4.3,4.5,4.7,4.6,3.9,4.4,4.5,4.9,3.7,3.3,3.8,4.6,4.9,4.7,4.8,5,"NA",3.1,4,4,4,3.6,4.8,4.8,2.3,4.3,4.2,3.8,4.7,3.6,4.1,4.3,4.4,3.5,4.2,3.4,3,4.9,4,5,4,4.2,3.1,4.6,3.9,4,5,4.2,4.4,3.6,5,4.5,4.3,4.8,4.6,4.4,3.5,4.6,3.1,3.5,2.9,5,"NA",5,3.7,5,3.5,4.6,3.4,3.4))
Training <- factor(c( "V", "V", "V", "L", "L", "V", "V", "V", "V", "L", "V", "V", "L", "V", "L", "V", "V", "L", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "L", "V", "V", "L", "V", "L", "V", "V", "V", "L", "V", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "V", "V", "L", "L", "L", "V", "V", "L", "L", "V", "V", "L", "V", "V", "V", "L", "V", "V", "L", "L", "L", "V", "V", "V", "L", "L", "V", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "V", "L", "L", "V", "V", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "V", "V", "L", "L", "V", "L", "V", "V", "V", "V", "L", "L", "V", "V", "V", "V", "L", "V", "V", "L", "V", "L", "V", "V", "L", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "L", "V", "V", "L", "V", "L", "V", "V", "V", "L", "V", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "V", "V", "L", "L", "L", "V", "V", "L", "L", "V", "V", "L", "V", "V", "V", "L", "V", "V", "L", "L", "L", "V", "V", "V", "L", "L", "V", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "V", "L", "L", "V", "V", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "V", "V", "L", "L", "V", "L", "V"))
company <- factor(c( "H", "H", "U", "U", "C", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "K", "U", "U", "G", "U", "C", "C", "G", "G", "U", "U", "U", "U", "C", "G", "C", "U", "K", "U", "U", "G", "B", "C", "U", "G", "H", "U", "U", "U", "C", "G", "G", "K", "K", "U", "G", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "U", "U", "K", "G", "H", "H", "G", "C", "H", "G", "G", "G", "B", "U", "U", "U", "B", "K", "K", "K", "U", "K", "U", "G", "K", "U", "G", "U", "U", "U", "K", "K", "K", "C", "H", "H", "H", "U", "U", "C", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "K", "U", "U", "G", "U", "C", "C", "G", "G", "U", "U", "U", "U", "C", "G", "C", "U", "K", "U", "U", "G", "B", "C", "U", "G", "H", "U", "U", "U", "C", "G", "G", "K", "K", "U", "G", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "U", "U", "K", "G", "H", "H", "G", "C", "H", "G", "G", "G", "B", "U", "U", "U", "B", "K", "K", "K", "U", "K", "U", "G", "K", "U", "G", "U", "U", "U", "K", "K", "K", "C", "H"))
Time <- factor(c( "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2"))

DataSet <- data.frame(ID, Training, company, Time, OutcomeMean)
str(DataSet)

#Remove NA
DataSet <- DataSet %>%
  filter(OutcomeMean != "NA")

#Participants per training in each company
table(DataSet$company, DataSet$Training)

#Model ID nested in company
Model_A<-lmer(OutcomeMean~ Time*Training + (1|company/ID), data=DataSet)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
summary(Model_A)
```

Here is the output of the summary(Model_A)

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML.
  t-tests use Satterthwaite's method [
lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: 
OutcomeMean ~ Time * Training + (1 | company/ID)
   Data: DataSet

REML criterion at convergence: 300.9

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.5372 -0.4916  0.0240  0.5371  2.5429 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance
 ID:company (Intercept) 0.1275  
 company    (Intercept) 0.0000  
 Residual               0.2002  
 Std.Dev.
 0.3570  
 0.0000  
 0.4475  
Number of obs: 178, groups:  
ID:company, 91; company, 6

Fixed effects:
                  Estimate Std. Error
(Intercept)        4.14532    0.08700
TimeT2             0.02066    0.09739
TrainingV         -0.15401    0.12122
TimeT2:TrainingV   0.16412    0.13487
                        df t value
(Intercept)      154.66314  47.646
TimeT2            89.00878   0.212
TrainingV        153.24518  -1.271
TimeT2:TrainingV  87.29814   1.217
                 Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        <2e-16 ***
TimeT2              0.832    
TrainingV           0.206    
TimeT2:TrainingV    0.227    
---
Signif. codes:  
  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’
  0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) TimeT2 TrnngV
TimeT2      -0.560              
TrainingV   -0.718  0.402       
TmT2:TrnngV  0.404 -0.722 -0.556
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

Comment: Do participants take both trainings or just one?

Comment: Also, in your two formulas, you have different left-hand sides, is this intentional?

Comment: No, Participants took just one Training Frank. And no, the companies where in the same country nut different cities.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I Edit now the formulas, and the difference should be in the Random effects, which is part of my question.

Comment: How do you compute the ICC?

Comment: performance::icc(Model_A, by_group=TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

Since each participant takes only one training, I would suggest not using the `ID` variable at all and doing the following: since you are interested in the difference between `OutcomeMean` before and after the training, create a variable for this difference, call it `diff` and then use the formula

```
diff ~ (1 | company) + (1 | Training)
```

This gives you the "overall" random effect of `company` and the "overall" random effect for `Training`. If you want the random effects for each combination of `company` and `Training`, use this formula:

```
diff ~ (1 | Training:company)
```

Comment: Thanks @Frank, but again I had the same _"boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')"_.
Could it be possible that is due to the *OutcomeMean* is not significant different between companies, neither within? (I just performed an ANOVA between company & Time).

Comment: @EstefanyReyBecerra Did you get the error for both?

Comment: yes both with the same Singularity. The models run, but the variance is Zero.

Comment: @EstefanyReyBecerra could you post the `summary()` of your fit? And what is the size of your data set? Can you maybe even post the dataset?

Comment: now you can find it in the main part ~ once again, thanks for your help!

Comment: It does seem to me that there is no company-related variance in your outcome variable. If you plot your outcome by Time, training and company  (e.g. plot<-ggplot(DataSet, aes(x=Time, y=OutcomeMean, color=Training)+geom_jitter()+facet_wrap(~company), which you probably have already done, but anyway you can see from the plot that companies do not form clusters across time/Training. This can be because companies genuinely don't differ in terms of outcome ~ time*training or there can be some coding or restructuring error.

Comment: @Sointu Thanks for your answer. Yes, I did before but I was not sure about the Singularity issue. Then I may run models without nesting the ID because they do not differ between companies, right? 
Model_C<-lmer(OutcomeMean ~ Time*Training + (1|ID), data=DataSet)

Comment: Yes, that's the code I would use in this situation. You can report it e.g. "Initially, random effect of company was included into the model. However, company-related variance was essentially zero, producing singular fit. Therefore, random effect of company was omitted from the final model." <- I'm not sure if this is the best formulation, but you catch my meaning. Good luck!